# How to find 4 lines of this white blob with HoughLines?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, hough-transform, houghlines

i am trying to draw 4 lines on every side of the white rectangle using **Houghlines** method.
This is the image i am working on [Source image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWzd2.png)  (2592 x 1246 image).

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
img = cv.imread("picture_compress.bmp")
img_gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv.Canny(img_gray, 100, 200, 5)
lines = cv.HoughLines(edges, rho=2, theta=np.pi / 180, threshold=200)  # lines will be in polar coordinate system
colors = [(0, 0, 255), (0, 255, 0), (255, 0, 0), (255, 0, 255), (255, 255, 0), (0, 255, 255)]

for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    rho, theta = line[0]    # rho --> distance from the coordinate origin (0,0) (Top-Left corner of the image)
                            # theta --> line rotation angle in radius
    # getting the cos(theta) and sin(theta) value
    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = np.sin(theta)
    # getting the origin value(top-left corner of the image)
    x0 = a * rho
    y0 = b * rho
    # 2 points
    pt1 = (int(x0 + 2592 * (-b)), int(y0 + 2592 * a))
    pt2 = (int(x0 - 2592 * (-b)), int(y0 - 2592 * a))
    # draw lines on the input image
    cv.line(img, pt1, pt2, colors[i % len(colors)], thickness=3, lineType=cv.LINE_AA)
print("Total number of lines:", str(len(lines)))
cv.namedWindow("Hough", cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv.imshow("Hough", img)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

the result i am i getting [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGiOL.png).

From the last image you can see that multiple lines are drawn on the edges of the white blob.

**Tasks**:

1. What is the best way to draw only 4 lines on each side of the rectangle ?
2. How can i get 4 finite lines by using only **HoughLines** only and not **HoughLinesP** ?

*-------------------------------------------------- **EDITED (17/03/2021)** --------------------------------------------------*

Let me post the [Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMF1t.jpg) which i am working on.

Fase 1: [Eroded_Dilated_Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHOfx.png) - the result after applying **erosion** and **dilation** and filling the blob. The code for this:

```
# This function is used for cleaning the image
def erode_dilate(img, num_iter):                    
    kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
    erosion = cv.erode(src=img, kernel=kernel, iterations=num_iter)
    dilation = cv.dilate(src=erosion, kernel=kernel, iterations=num_iter) 
    return dilation

# This function will search for the blob with max area and will fill it
def find_draw_big_blob(img): 
    contours, _ = cv.findContours(image=img, mode=cv.RETR_TREE, method=cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    contour_area = [cv.contourArea(cnt) for cnt in contours]      # List of contours' area
    id_max_area = np.argmax(contour_area)     
    label_max_image = np.zeros(img.shape)
    draw_max_contour = cv.drawContours(image=label_max_image, contours=contours, contourIdx=id_max_area, color=255, thickness=-1)  

img = cv.imread("25559.bmp")
gray_image = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret1, thresh = cv.threshold(gray_image, thresh=127, maxval=255, type=cv.THRESH_OTSU)
image_erode_dilate = erode_dilate(img=thresh, num_iter=2)
big_blob = find_draw_big_blob(img=image_erode_dilate)
cv.imshow("Image", big_blob)
```

Fase 2: [houghlines_Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0289U.png) - the final result after applying **hough trasform**. The code i used for this hough transform is already up in the question.

But the final result is not the result that i want.
I would like to achieve the following result shown in this [sample_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YD7OK.png)

Comment: You can check this => https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html#probabilistic-hough-transform

Comment: I already went through this tutorial. It did not solve my problem. Thank you. @MohitChandel

Answer (score 1):

- *What is the best way to draw only 4 lines on each side of the rectangle ?*

The best way to draw only 4-lines on each side of the rectangle is using [fast-line-detector](https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/ded/group__ximgproc__fast__line__detector.html)

Below you can see how fast-line-detector works:

[image]

Code:

---

```py
# Load the library
import cv2

# Load the image
img = cv2.imread("BWzd2.png")

# Convert to gray-scale
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Init. the fast-line-detector (fld)
fld = cv2.ximgproc.createFastLineDetector().detect(gry)

# Detect the lines
for line in fld:

    # Get current coordinates
    x1 = int(line[0][0])
    y1 = int(line[0][1])
    x2 = int(line[0][2])
    y2 = int(line[0][3])

    # Draw the line
    cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 255), 5)

# Display
cv2.imshow("img", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful. Can you achieve this by using hough transform ?

Comment: No. At least you need to guess the following parameters: `rho`, `theta` and `threshold`. The values in the [example](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html#probabilistic-hough-transform) won't efficiently detect the corners. Yet in your trial you set some constant values. The constant values change from example to example.

Comment: I appreciate your comment.

Answer (score 1):

In your Python/OpenCV code, simply increase your threshold to 250 or double your theta angle.

Input:

[image]

**1) Increase threshold**

```
lines = cv.HoughLines(edges, rho=2, theta=np.pi / 180, threshold=250)  # lines will be in polar coordinate system
```

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
img = cv.imread("picture_compress.png")
img_gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv.Canny(img_gray, 100, 200, 5)
lines = cv.HoughLines(edges, rho=2, theta=np.pi / 180, threshold=250)  # lines will be in polar coordinate system
colors = [(0, 0, 255), (0, 255, 0), (255, 0, 0), (255, 0, 255), (255, 255, 0), (0, 255, 255)]

result = img.copy()
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    rho, theta = line[0]    # rho --> distance from the coordinate origin (0,0) (Top-Left corner of the image)
                            # theta --> line rotation angle in radius
    # getting the cos(theta) and sin(theta) value
    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = np.sin(theta)
    # getting the origin value(top-left corner of the image)
    x0 = a * rho
    y0 = b * rho
    # 2 points
    pt1 = (int(x0 + 2592 * (-b)), int(y0 + 2592 * a))
    pt2 = (int(x0 - 2592 * (-b)), int(y0 - 2592 * a))
    # draw lines on copy of the input image
    cv.line(result, pt1, pt2, colors[i % len(colors)], thickness=3, lineType=cv.LINE_AA)
print("Total number of lines:", str(len(lines)))
cv.namedWindow("Hough", cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv.imshow("Hough", result)
cv.waitKey(0)

cv.imwrite("picture_compress_lines1.png", result)
```

[image]

**2) Increase your theta, e.g. double it:**

```
lines = cv.HoughLines(edges, rho=2, theta=2*np.pi / 180, threshold=200)  # lines will be in polar coordinate system
```

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
img = cv.imread("picture_compress.png")
img_gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv.Canny(img_gray, 100, 200, 5)
lines = cv.HoughLines(edges, rho=2, theta=2*np.pi / 180, threshold=200)  # lines will be in polar coordinate system
colors = [(0, 0, 255), (0, 255, 0), (255, 0, 0), (255, 0, 255), (255, 255, 0), (0, 255, 255)]

result = img.copy()
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    rho, theta = line[0]    # rho --> distance from the coordinate origin (0,0) (Top-Left corner of the image)
                            # theta --> line rotation angle in radius
    # getting the cos(theta) and sin(theta) value
    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = np.sin(theta)
    # getting the origin value(top-left corner of the image)
    x0 = a * rho
    y0 = b * rho
    # 2 points
    pt1 = (int(x0 + 2592 * (-b)), int(y0 + 2592 * a))
    pt2 = (int(x0 - 2592 * (-b)), int(y0 - 2592 * a))
    # draw lines on copy of the input image
    cv.line(result, pt1, pt2, colors[i % len(colors)], thickness=3, lineType=cv.LINE_AA)
print("Total number of lines:", str(len(lines)))
cv.namedWindow("Hough", cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv.imshow("Hough", result)
cv.waitKey(0)

cv.imwrite("picture_compress_lines2.png", result)
```

[image]

**The textual data from the Hough lines says:**

```
Total number of lines: 5
```

But I only see 4 lines.

Comment: Kudos to you sir. I just wonder why did you say only increase threshold? For instance, why not increasing `rho` or `theta`? Regards

Comment: I did say you could increase theta. Changing rho will likely not help. I would change the threshold before trying to change theta in hopes of keeping more accurate angles on the lines.

Comment: @fmw42 Hi, i have tried to do what you suggested but this doesnt help. In the answers i just shared the original image and the code. Could you please check it

Comment: Works fine for me. See my edited answer with the full code, which is yours with a slight change from me to save the resulting images.

Comment: @fmw42 I am not able to find the full code with changes.

Comment: Not sure what happened. It was there at one time. I will have to add it again.

Comment: Thanks.
Could you please check my edited question where i shared the original image and the code.

Comment: Try cv2.houghlinesP() at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga8618180a5948286384e3b7ca02f6feeb